# How to extract GeoServer usage details using REST API?

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, rest, geoserver-monitor

I am using GeoServer 2.19.0 version on CentOS along with monitor extension.

Wanted to fetch certain details on daily basis (such as what are the top 5 map requests ?,  How many users accessing GeoServer ? Etc.)

Exploring GeoServer REST API for the same. Has anyone tried this information ?

Useful links :

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/query.html

https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/rest/index.html

Comment: I have a feeling it may be easier to get some of those statistics (specifically around number of users) from your overarching webservice software (eg: Tomcat) - I don't think geoserver knows 'where' specific requests are made from. Depends on setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The monitoring module allows to collect information about requests regardless of how they are made (POST/GET, different versions of the protocol). However, the database storage for the module has shown to be a performance bottleneck and it has been deprecated. Better to use the module in "audit" mode, let it log the requests on text file, and then collect those information with a separate process. We use the ELK stack for that, logstash to collect the logs, elasticsearch to store them, kibana to create dashboards that can answer questions such as the most used layer, the slowest requests, and so on.